# How can I get the file system type using API in OSX/macOS?

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-sierra

Now I'm using `statfs` to get the file system type. I thought that the value of `f_type` from the returned `struct statfs` is one of those define in `enum fs_type_num` from http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-3248.60.10/bsd/vfs/vfs_conf.c

Until macOS 10.12 the value of `f_type` from `struct statfs` was 17 for HFS/HFS+. On macOS 10.12 the value is 23, and I don't see this value defined in `enum fs_type_num`.

It's there a file where the possible values of `f_type` from `struct statfs` are defined?

Or, it's there a better API to get the file system type?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me.

First of all include mount.h.

`#include <sys/mount.h>`

Then the following will give you the type, subtype and type name.

```
struct statfs output;
statfs("/", &output);
NSLog(@"Type: %u", output.f_type);
NSLog(@"Subtype: %u", output.f_fssubtype);
NSLog(@"Type name: %s", output.f_fstypename);
```

This works across macOS and iOS.

And for anyone that's curious here's the results I got across a handful of devices.

> macOS on 10.12.3
>
> - Type: 23
> - Subtype: 1
> - Type name: hfs
>
> iPhone on 10.2.1
>
> - Type: 23
> - Subtype: 3
> - Type name: hfs
>
> iPad on 10.3
>
> - Type: 22
> - Subtype: 1
> - Type name: apfs